# PHP: $pdf->image crashes (TCPDF)

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF and FPDI to create a new PDF and want to add an image (with alpha transparency) over one whole page.
Strangely enough, TCPDF sometimes creates a PDF and sometimes just crashes without an error (ie. doesn't produce any output at all, besides a standard response header (for text/html). It always depends on the dimensions I pass to the image function:

```
       $this->Image($markupfile,0,0,120, 50, 'png', '', '', true, 300);
```

works (albeit with a much too small image), however

```
       $this->Image($markupfile,0,0,1200, 50, 'png', '', '', true, 300);
```

does not. The original dimensions are width: 968px; height: 685px;

```
    require_once "config/sessions_class.php";
    require_once "config/sanitation_class.php";
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('FPDF/fpdi.php');
    require_once('config/settings.php');
    require_once('phpfpm/pdfVersion.php');



 class concatPdf extends FPDI{

     ....

    function concat() {
                $dir = $this->dir;
                $pagecount = $this->setSourceFile($dir.$this->file);
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
                    $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage($i);
                    $s = $this->getTemplatesize($this->_tplIdx);
                    $this->AddPage($s['w'] > $s['h'] ? 'L' : 'P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
                    $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);
                    $markupfile = "markups/".$this->pdfid."_".$i.".png";
                    if ( file_exists  ($markupfile)) {
                           $this->Image($markupfile,0,0,1020, 50, 'png', '', '', true, 300);

                    }

                 }

     }

     ....

  }



    $filename;
    $pdf = new concatPdf();

    $pdf->setImageScale(1.53);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 40);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 40, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

    $pdf->concat();

    $pdf->Output('ed_'."filename", 'I');
```

Comment: Aren't you just reaching `memory_limit` with such larger image?

Comment: interesting idea, let me check that...  echo memory_get_usage() outputs 27958520 - is that too much? the limit is set to 128M

Comment: I just increased the memory limit and set it to 512MB, still the same issue. And 27958520 bytes are roughly 26MB, so I dont believe memory should be an issue.